# Name for a class that only create and store instances?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a name for a class that only initialize and store instances of an different objects ?

```
class MyInitializerOfMyObjectAndStorage

public MyInitializerOfMyObjectAndStorage(CollectionOfInfoHowToInitialize)
{
   foreach (var item in CollectionOfInfoHowToInitialize)
       instances.add(new MyObject(item));
   ............................
}


private or public MyObject _instances;
```

Comment: factory returns a object from the caller over an method and object pool keep instances in (memory or something else) to return a instance if is needed.

Comment: A factory is an object that creates objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are breaking the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) The class is doing two things initializing and storing objects and this is why you find it hard to name. You can separate this class into two classes one is

```
public class ObjectInitializer {


  public Object initialize() {
    //return some object 
    return null;
  }
}
```

and the other is

```
public class ObjectsStore {


  public void store(Object someObject) {
   // do something here .. 
  }
}
```